# $\sigma (xy) \subseteq \sigma (x)\sigma (y)$ in Banach algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, spectra

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra(with unit $e$), $x,y \in A$ and $xy=yx$. Prove that $\sigma(xy) \subseteq \sigma (x) \sigma (y)$, also $\sigma (x+y)\subseteq \sigma(x)+\sigma(y)$. Where $\sigma$ means the spectrum.

---

Here $\sigma(x) \sigma(y)=\{ \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \in \mathcal{C}: \lambda_1 \in \sigma(x), \lambda_2 \in \sigma(y)\} $, and similarly for $\sigma(x)+\sigma(y)$.

For my attempt, let $B$ be the closed subalgebra generate by $e$, $x$ and $y$. Then $B$ is commutative. Denote $\Delta_{B}$ by the maximal ideal space of $B$. Then we have $\sigma_B(x)=\{ \phi(x): \phi \in \Delta_{B} \}$, and similarly for $y$,$x+y$, $xy$. Use $\phi$ is multiple linear functional,it’s clear $\sigma_{B}(x+y)\subseteq \sigma_{B}(x)+\sigma_{B}(y)$ and $\sigma_{B}(xy)\subseteq \sigma_{B}(x)\sigma_{B}(y)$. But $\sigma_{B}(x)$ maybe larger than $\sigma(x)$. And I don’t know how to continue. I know that the spectrum radical is keep invariant for subalgebra, so $r(x+y)\leq r(x)+r(y)$ and $r(xy)\leq r(x)r(y)$, this is a standard result on Rudin’s Functional Analysis.

This is an exercise from another book. But I heavily doubt the claim of this exercise is not true...

Any help or hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subalgebra generated by $e, x, y$, consider some maximal commutative subalgebra $C$ that contains $x, y$ (it exists because union of ascending chain of such subalgebras is also commutative subalgebra).

We can show that $a \in C \leftrightarrow \forall b \in C: ab = ba$ - this implies $C$ is closed and if $a \in C$ is inversible then $a^{-1} \in C$.

So if $a \in C$, then $a - \lambda e$ is inversible in $C$ iff it's inversible in $A$, and your proof works.

Comment: Nice answer, mihaild. If we let $C$ be the commutative subalgebra generate by $a$, $b$, $e$ and $(\lambda e-a)^{-1}$, also $(\lambda e-b)^{-1}$ for all $\lambda \in \rho(a)$ or $\rho(b)$. It also work?

Comment: This algebra isn't necessary complete, so I am not sure all the tools about complex homomorphisms will work. If we will take subalgebra generated by this elements and also $(\lambda e - ab)^{-1}$, $(\lambda e - (a + b))^{1}$ and so on it will probably work, but we will need to carefully check that spectres of elements we are interested in relative to our subalgebra coincide with spectres relative to $A$.